# How to resize Webbrowser content to fit 480 x 800

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, browser

Im using some basic code to display a mobile website in my application using a web browser.

For some reason, if I use the standard browser it is sized correcly to 480 x 800 , but when I use the web browser in my application the page is way off more like 960 x 800.

Is there a way to force the size the page is displayed in the web browser?

The funny thing is that it was working a few months ago, but has suddenly gone haywire.

code is :

```
    string site1 = "http://m.domain.com";
   webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri(site1, UriKind.Absolute));
   webBrowser1.Navigated += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs>(webBrowser1_Navigated);
```

I was thinking I could force user agent by using the below code, but I am getting errors " no overload for method, 'Navigate' takes 4 arguments.

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/run.php", null, null, "User-Agent: Windows Phone 7");
```

Page using app:

[image]

Page using standard IE9 browser outside of application, but on handset.

[image: using ie9 outside of application]

Comment: `We are having trouble identifying your mobile...`.  So you got the web page that wasn't optimized to be displayed on a small screen.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent

Comment: @Hans Passant as you can see from the second image, it is sized correctly using the standard browser on the phone.

Comment: Sure, it didn't have any trouble identifying your phone.  So you got the page made for a phone.  This doesn't have anything to do with the browser size, it has everything to do with the web page you got from the server.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, I agree. So, is there an option for the browser to specfiy page size? Or any other solution you can think of?

Comment: It already does.  Contact your phone company for support.

Comment: @Hans Passant Contant my phone company? Its an issue with the webbrowser control, in silverlight as it obviously works in the other standard phone browser.

Comment: @Rhys: have you, as Matt suggested, used Fiddler to see the differences in both the request and response?  It's probably something like a user-agent difference in the request so the server is returning different response HTML to you.

Comment: @ctacke Yes, and I believe thats the issue. I am attempting to use `webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/run.php", null, null, "User-Agent: Windows Phone 7");` to change user agent, but its throwing an error "No overload for method 'Navigate' takes 4 arguments"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One place to start would be to sniff the request/response.  There's clearly different HTML coming back from the server for the two requests.  For the in-app browser, it clearly says it's having trouble identifying the device.  If you can figure out what is different between the two requests, you might be able to force the in-app browser to make the request more like the out-of-app browser.

If you're using the simulator, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is a fantastic tool for that sort of thing.   The first place I'd look is at the User-Agent header, which most sites use to figure out what type of browser is requesting the page.

Comment: I think the images are misleading, I have updated them. As you can see now, the content is the same, the only issue is that it is sized correctly using IE9 browser on the phone, but not using the webbrowser in the application. How would I "force the browser to make the request more like the out-of-app browser"? Thats the big question

Comment: That's where fiddler comes in.  You need to see what is different about the request in those two cases.  It's possible that the embedded browser is simply using a different rendering engine than the out-of-app browser, in which case I'm not sure what you can do.

Comment: I think your right about the user agent. I am trying to change the user agent using the code I have updated on my post. Still having issues though. Perhaps you have the answer?